# plot_surface with inverse matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix-inverse

I am trying to plot a 3D surface using matplotlib's plot_surface function. My f(x, y) function is complicated. I'm using inverse matrix which causes an error "Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square".

But when I'm trying to plot surface using matplotlib's plot everything is fine and no error occurs,I get a wireframe surface.
How can I solve this problem with inverse matrix and plot surface?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sympy import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = np.arange(52, 100, 4)
y = np.arange(1.5, 2, 0.05)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x,y):
    L = 0.53*y
    l_2 = 0.2*y
    x_s = 0.004 
    m_1 = 0.19*x
    m_2 = 0.62*x
    l_1 = 0.3167*y
    
    R = 0.45
    r = 0.41
    h = 0.38
    b = 0.2
    d = 0.12
    M_0 = 2.2

    k = 5
    g = 9.8

    Q = x*g*x_s
    I_1 = M_0*d**2
    I_2 = m_1*L**2/3
    I_3 = m_2*(b**2+l_2**2)/3
    A_0 = M_0*(R-r)**2+2*m_1*((R-h)**2+b**2)+m_2*(R-h+l_2)**2+I_1+I_3
    B_0 = 2*m_1*l_1*(R-h)+m_2*L*(R-h+l_2)
    C_0 = 2*m_1*l_1**2+m_2*L**2+2*I_2
    w = g*(M_0*r+2*m_1*h-m_2*(l_2-h))
    v = -g*(2*m_1*l_1+m_2*L)
    
    
    M = np.array([[A_0, B_0], [B_0, C_0]])
    N = np.array([[k, -k], [-k, k]])
    K = np.array([[w, 0], [0,v]])
    D = np.array([-1,1])

    M_1 = np.linalg.inv(M) #error

    N_0 = np.dot(M_1, N)
    K_0 = np.dot(M_1, K)
    D_0 = np.dot(M_1, D)
    D_0 = D_0.reshape(-1,1)

    F_0 = np.concatenate ([eye(2), zeros(2)], axis = 1)
    F = np.concatenate([-N_0, -K_0], axis = 1)
    F = np.concatenate([F, F_0])
    F = np.array(F, dtype = float)
    zer = np.array([[0],[0]])
    H = np.concatenate([D_0, zer])
    t,T = np.linalg.eig(F)

    for i in range(4):
        if re(t[i]) > 0:
            j = i
    
    T_0 = np.linalg.inv(T)
    P = np.dot(T_0,H)
    p = P[j,0]
    s = t[j]
    s = float(s)
    return Q*abs(p)*180/(pi*s*abs(T_0[j,2]))

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,f(X,Y))
plt.show()
```

Comment: The shape of matrix `M` is `(2, 2, 10, 12)`. The size `10` is different `12`, so can't to invert.

Comment: Thank you
But why does this happen? When x and y are fixed, there is no problem with the inverse matrix.

Comment: Try to change the assignment order to `M`. The internals matrices in `M` must be square.

Comment: Check the Numpy functions like `concatenate`, `stack`, `vstack`, `dstack`, `block`, `hstack`, `column_stack`... Maybe fix it

Comment: I THINK that what you want is `np.linalg.inv(M.transpose((2,3,0,1))` but I don't understand what you want to do next with `M_1`, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: I tried to execute your code... no way. You mixed the arrays' dimensions and it's not clear what you're trying to do – or at least it's unclear to me. My previous suggestion is still valid, though.